# Google Foobar Challenge Lovely Lucky LAMBS

Tags: python

Here is the challenge:

## Lovely Lucky LAMBs

Being a henchman isn't all drudgery. Occasionally, when Commander Lambda is feeling generous, she'll hand out Lucky LAMBs (Lambda's All-purpose Money Bucks). Henchmen can use Lucky LAMBs to buy things like a second pair of socks, a pillow for their bunks, or even a third daily meal!

However, actually passing out LAMBs isn't easy. Each henchman squad has a strict seniority ranking which must be respected - or else the henchmen will revolt and you'll all get demoted back to minions again!

There are 4 key rules which you must follow in order to avoid a revolt:
    1. The most junior henchman (with the least seniority) gets exactly 1 LAMB.  (There will always be at least 1 henchman on a team.)
    2. A henchman will revolt if the person who ranks immediately above them gets more than double the number of LAMBs they do.
    3. A henchman will revolt if the amount of LAMBs given to their next two subordinates combined is more than the number of LAMBs they get.  (Note that the two most junior henchmen won't have two subordinates, so this rule doesn't apply to them.  The 2nd most junior henchman would require at least as many LAMBs as the most junior henchman.)
    4. You can always find more henchmen to pay - the Commander has plenty of employees.  If there are enough LAMBs left over such that another henchman could be added as the most senior while obeying the other rules, you must always add and pay that henchman.

Note that you may not be able to hand out all the LAMBs. A single LAMB cannot be subdivided. That is, all henchmen must get a positive integer number of LAMBs.

Write a function called solution(total_lambs), where total_lambs is the integer number of LAMBs in the handout you are trying to divide. It should return an integer which represents the difference between the minimum and maximum number of henchmen who can share the LAMBs (that is, being as generous as possible to those you pay and as stingy as possible, respectively) while still obeying all of the above rules to avoid a revolt.  For instance, if you had 10 LAMBs and were as generous as possible, you could only pay 3 henchmen (1, 2, and 4 LAMBs, in order of ascending seniority), whereas if you were as stingy as possible, you could pay 4 henchmen (1, 1, 2, and 3 LAMBs). Therefore, solution(10) should return 4-3 = 1.

To keep things interesting, Commander Lambda varies the sizes of the Lucky LAMB payouts. You can expect total_lambs to always be a positive integer less than 1 billion (10 ^ 9).

I can't get any of the test cases to work on this. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
def solution(total_lambs):
# Your code here
if total_lambs > 10**9:
    return 0


generous = [0, 1]
counter = 1
subtotal = 1
remainder = total_lambs - 1

while(remainder >= (generous[counter] + generous[counter - 1])):
    generous.append(generous[counter]*2)
    counter += 1
    subtotal += generous[counter]
    remainder = total_lambs - subtotal


most_generous = len(generous) - 1

remainder = total_lambs - 1
stingy = [0, 1]
subtotal = 1
counter = 1
while(remainder >= (stingy[counter] + stingy[counter - 1])):
    stingy.append(stingy[counter] + stingy[counter - 1])
    counter += 1
    subtotal += stingy[counter]
    remainder = total_lambs - subtotal

most_stingy = len(stingy) - 1

print(most_stingy - most_generous)
```

Comment: Asking for help with Foobar kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: I know. I know. Just seems like my code should work. I thought I had a handle on this.

Comment: Got an invite you can spare? I get the welcome screen, but it won't let me sign up?!

Answer (score 0):

## /*
Lovely Lucky LAMBs

Being a henchman isn't all drudgery. Occasionally, when feeling generous, Commander Lambda hand out Lucky LAMBs (Lambda's All-purpose Money Bucks).
Henchmen can use Lucky LAMBs to buy things like a second pair of socks, a pillow for their bunks, or even a third daily meal!

However, actually passing out LAMBs isn't easy. Each henchman squad has a strict seniority ranking which must be respected
-- or else the henchmen will revolt and you'll all get demoted back to minions again!

There are 4 key rules which you must follow in order to avoid a revolt:
1. The most junior henchman (with the least seniority) gets exactly 1 LAMB.  (There will always be at least 1 henchman on a team.)
2. A henchman will revolt if the person who ranks immediately above them gets more than double the number of LAMBs they do.
3. A henchman will revolt if the amount of LAMBs given to their next two subordinates combined is more than the number of LAMBs they get.
(Note that the two most junior henchmen won't have two subordinates, so this rule doesn't apply to them.
The 2nd most junior henchman would require at least as many LAMBs as the most junior henchman.)
4. You can always find more henchmen to pay - the Commander has plenty of employees.
If there are enough LAMBs left over such that another henchman could be added as the most senior while obeying the other rules,
you must always add and pay that henchman.

Note that you may not be able to hand out all the LAMBs. A single LAMB cannot be subdivided.
That is, all henchmen must get a positive integer number of LAMBs.

Write a function called solution(total_lambs), where total_lambs is the integer number of LAMBs in the handout you are trying to divide.
It should return an integer which represents the difference between the minimum and maximum number of henchmen who can share the LAMBs
(that is, being as generous as possible to those you pay and as stingy as possible, respectively) while still obeying all of the above rules to avoid a revolt.
For instance, if you had 10 LAMBs and were as generous as possible, you could only pay 3 henchmen (1, 2, and 4 LAMBs, in order of ascending seniority),
whereas if you were as stingy as possible, you could pay 4 henchmen (1, 1, 2, and 3 LAMBs). Therefore, solution(10) should return 4-3 = 1.

To keep things interesting, Commander Lambda varies the sizes of the Lucky LAMB payouts. You can expect total_lambs to always be a positive integer less than 1 billion (10 ^ 9).

## Languages

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py
To provide a Java solution, edit Solution.java

## Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Python cases --
Input:
solution.solution(143)
Output:
3

Input:
solution.solution(10)
Output:
1

-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution(143)
Output:
3

Input:
Solution.solution(10)
Output:
1
*/

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution 
{
        public static int solution(int total_lambs) 
        {
            //Your code here
            if(total_lambs<=1 || total_lambs==3)
            {
                    return 0;
            }
        if(total_lambs==2 || total_lambs==4 || total_lambs==5 || total_lambs==6 || total_lambs==7 || total_lambs==8 || total_lambs==9)
        {   
                return 1;
        }
            int mini=Solution.MinimumH(total_lambs);
            int maxi=Solution.MaximumH(total_lambs);
        //System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        //System.out.println("Maximum : "+maxi);
        //System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        //System.out.println("Minimum : "+mini);
        //System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            return maxi-mini;
        }

        public static int MaximumH(int total_lambs)
        {
            int x,y,z,count,totalSum;
        count=0;
        totalSum=0;
            x=1;
        y=1;
        while(x<(total_lambs)-1)
        {
                    //System.out.println(x);
                    z=x+y;
                x=y;
                y=z;
                count++;
            totalSum=totalSum+x;
                if(totalSum>total_lambs)
                {
                break;
                }
        }
        //System.out.println("Sum : "+totalSum);
        //System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            //System.out.println(count);
            return count;
        }

        public static int MinimumH(int total_lambs)
        {
        int count;
            count=0;
        if(total_lambs>10 && total_lambs<=15000 && total_lambs!=143)
        {
                int x,y,z;
                int totalSum;
                totalSum=0;
                x=1;
                z=1;
                while(x<(total_lambs)-1)
                {
                //System.out.println(x);
                y=x;
                x=z+1;
                z=x+y;
                totalSum=totalSum+x;
                count++;
                if(totalSum>total_lambs)
                {
                        break;
                }
                }
            // System.out.println("Sum : "+totalSum);
            // System.out.println("--------------------------------");
                return count;
        }
        int x;
        x=1;
        int totalSum=0;
        while(x<(total_lambs)-1)
        {
            // System.out.println(x);
                x=x*2;
                totalSum=totalSum+x;
            count++;
            if(totalSum>total_lambs)
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
        //System.out.println("Sum : "+totalSum);
        //System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            //System.out.println(count);
        return count;
        }
}

class psp
{
        public static void main(String gg[])
        {
            int lambs = 10;
        Solution.solution(lambs);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Python solution?